# NameError: name '' is not defined?

Tags: python

I've searched and this has been answered a lot already, but it mostly had to do with version errors. I checked my Python version (it's 3.4.2) but it still returns the error.

Code w/ error:

```
import random

def start():
    rannum = random.randint(0, 20)
    inpnum = int(input('Please enter a number between 0 and 20: '))
    calc()

def loop():
    inpnum = int(input('Please enter a number between 0 and 20: '))
    calc()

def calc():

    if inpnum > rannum:
        print('The number you entered is too high.')
        loop()

    if inpnum < rannum:
        print('The number you entered is too low.')
        loop()

    if inpnum == rannum:
        print('Congratulations! You guessed the number!')
        input('')

start()
```

This returns the error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "guessthenumber.py", line 26, in <module>
    start()
  File "guessthenumber.py", line 6, in start
    calc()
  File "guessthenumber.py", line 14, in calc
    if inpnum > rannum:
NameError: name 'inpnum' is not defined
```

I tried to fix it myself and changed it to look like this:

```
import random

def loop():
    inpnum = int(input('Please enter a number between 0 and 20: '))
    calc()

def calc():

    rannum = random.randint(0, 20)
    inpnum = int(input('Please enter a number between 0 and 20: '))

    if inpnum > rannum:
        print('The number you entered is too high.')
        loop()

    if inpnum < rannum:
        print('The number you entered is too low.')
        loop()

    if inpnum == rannum:
        print('Congratulations! You guessed the number!')
        input('')

calc()
```

It does work but it keeps making a new number (I think I know why, the rannum = random.randint(0, 20) keeps making up a new number every time) and it asks you for an input number twice (because it already asks for one at loop() but does so again in calc(), I think) so you have to randomly guess until you have it right because it keeps changing every guess.

To me it looks like complete Python code. Does anyone else know what to do here?

Comment: `inpnum` is never defined in `calc`, why are you surprised? Make it an explicit parameter.

Comment: You are having a problem related to lexical scope.  You should consider passing `inpnum` as an argument to `calc`.  e.g. "`def calc(inpnum):`.

Comment: http://puu.sh/fq2r7/08a12a2d96.png -- for the actual file

Comment: @EmilianSpo Never paste screenshots to code, always paste the actual text into pastebin instead.

Comment: Not pastebin, please provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question.

Comment: He already did this, but then OP pasted a comment, which is not a suitable place for code blocks

Comment: Also @EmilianSpo don't forget to set one of the answers to accepted, and to thank the person!

Comment: Wow, you didn't even thank anyone for helping you. Great job.

Comment: Sorry, I check my mail inbox rarely. That doesn't mean you have to be a dick though :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to change your calc function to accept an arguemnt:

```
def calc(num):
    # do stuff with num
```

and pass `ipnum` into it:

```
def loop():
    inpnum = int(input('Please enter a number between 0 and 20: '))
    calc(inpnum)
```

This is how you make use of local variables in one function in another function.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me on my way :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code to one function as follows then you can get around the scope issue:

example:

```
import random

def calc():
    rannum = random.randint(0, 20)         
    inputnum = None
    while inputnum != rannum:
        inpnum = int(input('Please enter a number between 0 and 20: '))
        if inpnum > rannum:
            print('The number you entered is too high.')
        elif inpnum < rannum:
            print('The number you entered is too low.')

    print('Congratulations! You guessed the number!')

calc()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go;

```
import random

def ask():
    rannum = random.randint(0, 20)
    print "Num: {}".format(rannum)
    while True:
        inpnum = int(input('Please enter a number between 0 and 20: '))
        if inpnum > rannum:
            print('The number you entered is too high.')
        elif inpnum < rannum:
            print('The number you entered is too low.')
        else:
            print('Congratulations! You guessed the number!')
            break

ask()
```

Result

```
$ python lol.py
Num: 18
Please enter a number between 0 and 20: 1
The number you entered is too low.
Please enter a number between 0 and 20: 20
The number you entered is too high.
Please enter a number between 0 and 20: 18
Congratulations! You guessed the number!
```

Answer (score 0):

This works. I put print() to make space between lines so it looks better.

```
import random

def loop():
    rannum = random.randint(0, 20)

    while True:

        inpnum = int(input('Please enter a number between 0 and 20: '))
        print ()
        if inpnum == rannum:
            print('Congratulations! You guessed the number!')
            print()
            break

        if inpnum > rannum:
            print('The number you entered is too high.')
            print()
            continue

        if inpnum < rannum:
            print('The number you entered is too low.')
            print()
            continue




loop()
```